# Как выполнять POST-запрос с периодичностью раз в сутки?

Tags: php

На сайте пользователь оставляет свой номер телефона. В базу пишется номер телефона и время отправки в формате timestamp.

Нужно каждому пользователю на протяжении 4-х дней раз в сутки (в то же время, в которое был оставлен номер телефона) отправлять SMS-сообщение. Количество новых регистраций в день от 500 и более.

Правильно ли будет сделать отправку следующим образом?

Раз в 10 минут запускаем скрипт через cron. Сам скрипт выполняет следующее:

1. Из базы вытаскивает все записи.
2. В цикле проверяет время всех записей.

   - Если время сейчас больше времени записи + 86400*4 (количество секунд в 4-х днях), то отправляем последнее сообщение и удаляем запись.
   - Если время сейчас больше 86400*3 но меньше 86400*4, отправляем третье сообщение.
   - Если время сейчас больше 86400*2 но меньше 86400*3, отправляем второе сообщение.
   - Если время сейчас больше 86400 но меньше 86400*2, отправляем первое сообщение.

Не будет ли тупить скрипт при большом количестве записей в базе (несколько тысяч)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если индекс правильный и сервер надежный то проблем не будет. (Как вариант, читать можно со slave базы).

> 500 в день
>
> 24*60*60 = 86400 - минут в день.
>
> Т.е в среднем за раз будет отправляться(10 мин крон)
>
> 500/8640 < 0.1 сообшение.

Для оптимизации можно пробовать очереди(RabbitMQ, Gearman, ZeroMQ).

**Вариант**

Kрон кидает в очередь работник из очереди забирает и делат отсылку sms. Легче масштабировать

**Второй вариант (RabbitMQ) создаем 5 очередей,**

Первай задаем жизнь(ttl) день, второй 2 и т.д.

Пятая очередь подключается как Dead Letter Queue к первым 4-м

После смерти (через день, 2 ...) сообшения попадут в 5 очередь через Dead Letter Exchange

Работник подключается к 5-й очереди и отправляет сообшение как только они туда приходят.

Когда пользователь подписывается кидаем работы в первые 4 очереди.

Таким образом нагрузки на базу нет вообще.