# Cron Задачи только с помощью php

Tags: php, cron

Здравствуйте!

Проблема в том что не смог найти нормальную, понятную документацию по созданию cron задач.Везде вижу вот что-то вроде этого 01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly но не могу понять куда его надо вставить.Ломаю голову уже 2 дня, решил обратиться к вам.Если есть нормальная документация под рукой или если сможете в кратце объяснить как создать задачу буду очень признателен.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Cron это Linux утилита которая по времени запускает какой-то файл .php.  Созадавать крон через PHP это извращение по-моему. Как собственно и решение любых задач кроме генерации HTML. Почитайте тут про управление Cron средствами php http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1153

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/434351/178576

Comment: `man cron` - вот вам нормальная, понятная документация по созданию cron-задач.

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно запускать php-скрипт по расписанию, правильно?

Для этого запускайте crontab в режиме редактирования: `#crontab -e`
В открывшемся файле пишете что-то вроде:

```
0 5 * * * php /path/to/script.php
```

Сохраняете и выходите. (Если это centos или подобное, то `esc, :wq , enter`).
Что представляет из себя эта строка:

```
Минута (0) Час(5) День_месяца(Каждый) Месяц(Каждый) День_недели(Каждый) команда(php /path/to/script.php).
```

То есть, script.php будет запускаться каждый день в 5:00 утра.

@koks_rs дал отличный [туториал](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1153)

Comment: Запустить crontab в режиме редактирования, я не могу понять эту строку,где её запускать и как её запускать?

Comment: В linux-консоли. В текстовом режиме.

Comment: А можно как то это сделать без консоли, только используя php?

Comment: @HakobShaghikyan, в первом комментарии к вашему вопросу ссылка дана на туториал.

Comment: @HakobShaghikyan скажите, а зачем вам делать это используя php, какую конечную задачу вы решаете?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Когда новый пользователь зарегистрировался на сайт, нужно ему отослать почту через 2 дня.

Comment: @HakobShaghikyan, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/581590/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8

Comment: Поправка полный путь до php нужен или он не сможет запустить его